# plane curve of degree 4

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was dealing with exercise IV.3.2 in Hartshorne, which says the following:

> Let $X$ be a plane curve of degree 4.
>
> - a) Show that the canonical divisors on $X$ are exactly the hyperplane divisors.
> - b) If $D$ is any effective divisor of degree 2 on $X$, then $\dim |D|=0$.
> - c) Conclude $X$ is not hyperelliptic.

To prove that $X$ is not hyperelliptic it is sufficient to use adjunction formula to obtain $\omega_X=O_X(1)$, so the canonical divisor $K$ is very ample, hence $X$ is not hyperelliptic. But I wanted to follow the exercise to get a more geometric view of the problem.

- a) The curve has genus 3 and so $l(K)=3$ and $\deg(K)=4$. Set $D:=X\cdot L$, where $L$ is a line. We then have that $D=p_1+...+p_4$ and thus by Riemann-Roch $$l(D)=2+l(K-D).$$ Since $K$ is bpf $l(K-D)\in \{0,1\}$, if it is $1$, we get $$K-D\sim 0,$$ as $\deg(K-D)=0$.

  Now, to prove $l(K-D)=1$, I would like to prove $l(D)=3$. *Is there a way of doing it by exploiting the fact that $D=X\cdot L$?*
- b) Let $P+Q$ be our degree 2 effective divisor. By Riemann-Roch $$l(P+Q)=l(K-P-Q)$$ and by adjunction we have K bpf as seen before and so $l(P+Q)=1,$ as required.

  *Is there a way to prove it exploiting a)?*
- c) follows by b).

Comment: The adjunction calculation actually does part (a) for you, since "the canonical divisors are precisely the hyperplane divisors" is just another way of saying "the canonical bundle is precisely $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1)|_X$."

Comment: Yes, but using adjunction you get to the conclusion without needing step a). I think there is a more geometric solution avoiding adjunction, which is what I am looking for. Probably my question is not so clear. My question is, giving a line, can you calculate $l(X\cdot L)$? Once this is done how to use a) to do b)?

Comment: You can directly compute $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(1))=h^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(1))=3$ from the exact sequence defining $X$ as a section of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Since $D=X\cap H$ is a linear section of $X$, then $l(D)=h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(1))$. This is exactly the same as using adjuction as Tabes suggested, but in this way you never use that word at least..

Answer (score 0):

The more geometric answer I was looking for is the following:

a) We are left to prove $\dim|X\cdot L|=2$ and this follows by the geometric version of Riemann-Roch giving $\dim \operatorname{span}\{p_1+\ldots p_4\}=\deg(X\cdot L)-1-\dim|X\cdot L|$. Since $p_i$ belongs to a line they span a line so we get $\dim|X\cdot L|=2$ as wanted.

b) Write $D=P_1+P_2$ and suppose there exists an effective divisor linear equivalent to $D$, $Q_1+Q_2$. Then taking the line through $P_1,P_2$ it intersects $X$ in other two points $P_3,P_4$ and by a), $$K\sim P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4\sim Q_1+Q_2+P_3+P_4,$$ hence $Q_1,Q_2$ belong to the same line containing $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$. Therefore $Q_1,Q_2$ must coincide with $P_1,P_2$. In conclusion we cannot find any such divisor, so $\dim|D|=0$.